# How type Inference "auto" and call by reference works?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

How `&c` works on this loop and in assigning,  `c = toupper(c)`?

```
string str = "hello";

for (auto & c: str)
  c = toupper(c);
```

Can you please explain?

Comment: Read [auto specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) and [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you have a specific error or error message, or are you asking specifically about the `&c` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that `std::toupper` has Undefined Behavior if it's served a negative value other than `EOF`. And with most compilers `char` is a signed type by default. On a typical 8-bit byte computer that means that if `c` has a value not in the range of ASCII, which is 0 through 127, then it's negative and you get UB.

A simple solution to *that* problem is to cast the argument to `unsigned char`:

```
auto to_upper( const char c )
    -> char
{
    using Byte = unsigned char;
    return static_cast<char>( toupper( static_cast<Byte>( c ) );
}
```

Still this function will by default only work for ASCII characters, the letters A through Z, because it assumes the encoding specified by the C level locale, and that's `"C"` by default, essentially limited to ASCII. But at least it avoids Undefined Behavior. So let's pretend that your example uses it,

```
for( auto& c : str ) c = to_upper( c );
```

That's a **range based `for` loop**, and it runs through all items in `str`, binding the reference `c` to each item and executing the loop body with that binding in effect. Since the items of `str` are of type `char`, the `auto` will be deduced as `char`. So it's the same as writing `for( char& c : str ) ...`.

So by default it uppercases all ASCII characters in `str`.

In Windows, if the C locale has been set via `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" )`, the assumed encoding will be Windows ANSI, and if `str` contains characters with that encoding `to_upper` will do its uppercasing job correctly. This means that in Windows it's possible to use it to e.g. uppercase a Norwegian string like `"Blåbærsyltetøy"`, provided that Windows' locale is one where Windows ANSI Western is used.

In *nix it doesn't help to call `setlocale` because the user's native locale will specify UTF-8 encoding, where each character outside of ASCII is represented as two or more bytes > 127.

Answer (score 0):

`auto & c` is equivalent to `char & c` which is a reference to each character in the string. Updating the value of the reference changes the referenced character in the string.

The result of the above code would be an uppercase string.

Comment: I wouldn't say `auto` is _equivalent_ to `char`, rather that it's _contextually inferred_ to be `char` here.